# How do I get the string from bigger string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings that follow this format:

`/users/john`, `/users/anna`, `/users/charles/something`

I want to get the users name. So, it's either the  word after `/users/` or the word after `/users/` and before another `/`.

How can I do that in javascript?

Comment: You have to  split from / sign then get the correct index

Comment: `string.split("/")[2]` will do.

Comment: @Khay But that wouldn't check if the string matches the expected format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the `/users/`, and then capture non-slashes in a group, and extract that group:

```js
['/users/john',
'/users/anna',
'/users/charles/something']
.forEach(str => {
  console.log(
    str.match(/\/users\/([^/]+)/)[1]
  )
});
```

Comment: Do you know why I might be getting this error: `no-useless-escape: Unnecessary escape character: \/.` in my editor?

Comment: Oops, apparently you don't have to escape forward slashes inside a character set here. Change to `[^/]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex replace with a capture group:

```js
var input = 'users/charles/something';
if (/^users\/.*$/.test(input)) {
    var username = input.replace(/^users\/([^\/]+).*/, "$1");
    console.log(username);
}
else {
    console.log("no match");
}
```

Comment: Why doing a replace instead of a 'match' as CertainPerformance suggested?

Comment: @HommerSmith His performance is not certain on JavaScript questions, I wasn't sure about `match`.